# Wagtail form file upload

Tags: django, wagtail

I have an issue when I add file upload field to Wagtail Forms Builder I get this error:

**Exception Type:   TypeError**

**Exception Value:  Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable**

This is my code:

```
class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    CHOICES = FORM_FIELD_CHOICES + (('fileupload', 'File Upload'),)
    page = ParentalKey('FormPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='form_fields')

    field_type = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='field type',
        max_length=16,
        # use the choices tuple defined above
        choices=CHOICES
    )

    api_fields = [
        APIField('page'),
    ]

class CustomFormBuilder(FormBuilder):

    def create_fileupload_field(self, field, options):
        return forms.FileField(**options)

class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    form_builder = CustomFormBuilder
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)
    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text', classname="full"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel('subject'),
        ], "Email"),
    ]
    # Export fields over the API
    api_fields = [
        APIField('intro'),
        APIField('thank_you_text'),
    ]
```

This is my template:

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
        {{ page.intro|richtext }}
        <form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Wagtail version 2.8.1
Django version 3.0.5
any idea with this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

The core issue here is that you are attempting to store an uploaded file as JSON. Wagtail's `FormBuilder` does not store the submission data parts as their own DB models but instead bundles is up as json (e.g. `{'field-a': 'value'}`) and stores that as a string in the database.

The reason for this is that the data stored is flexible on a per page basis and can change over time based on the page's settings.

So, to fully implement a file upload field, you need to store those files somewhere, plus solve a few other problems.

### 1. Where to store the file

- Depending on your Django setup, you will need to get a basic understanding of how to [Store files in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/)
- You will need to create a new model that will store these files, see `FormUploadedFile` in the example below
- Depending on your use case, you will need to consider multiple files uploaded in each form submission, as the `FormPage` UI enables users to create multiple of any field type, hence it might be good to keep a reference to the field name it is stored under.

### 2. What to save in the JSON as a reference to the file

- This could be a simple pk (primary key) reference, as per the code example below.
- You may want to add some more advanced linking between the file upload model and the `FormSubmission` model for better data integrity
- You will need to override the `process_form_submission` on your `FormPage` model, you can see the original code here https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/contrib/forms/models.py#L195

### 3. Reading the file and what to represent as this file in the form submissions list

- You may want to modify the `get_data` output from the `FormSubmission` records, you can do this by adding a custom `FormSubmission` model (see code below), however this will be in place of your existing model (so your existing submissions will no longer be visible without some sort of migration or other workaround).
- You can see the original `get_data` method here https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/contrib/forms/models.py#L48
- The Wagatil docs section has a good part about [customising the submissions list](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.8.1/reference/contrib/forms/customisation.html#customise-form-submissions-listing-in-wagtail-admin)

## Example Code

Here is a rough working POC to get you started, hope this helps.

```py
import json

from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.db import models
from django import forms

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey

from wagtail.contrib.forms.models import (
    AbstractEmailForm, AbstractFormField, AbstractFormSubmission, FORM_FIELD_CHOICES)
from wagtail.contrib.forms.forms import FormBuilder
from wagtail.contrib.forms.views import SubmissionsListView


class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    page = ParentalKey('FormPage', related_name='form_fields', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field_type = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='field type',
        max_length=16,
        choices=FORM_FIELD_CHOICES + (('fileupload', 'File Upload'),)
    )


class CustomFormBuilder(FormBuilder):

    def create_fileupload_field(self, field, options):
        return forms.FileField(**options)


class CustomSubmissionsListView(SubmissionsListView):
    """
    further customisation of submission list can be done here
    """
    pass


class CustomFormSubmission(AbstractFormSubmission):
    # important - adding this custom model will make existing submissions unavailable
    # can be resolved with a custom migration

    def get_data(self):
        """
        Here we hook in to the data representation that the form submission returns
        Note: there is another way to do this with a custom SubmissionsListView
        However, this gives a bit more granular control
        """

        file_form_fields = [
            field.clean_name for field in self.page.specific.get_form_fields()
            if field.field_type == 'fileupload'
        ]

        data = super().get_data()

        for field_name, field_vale in data.items():
            if field_name in file_form_fields:
                # now we can update the 'representation' of this value
                # we could query the FormUploadedFile based on field_vale (pk)
                # then return the filename etc.
                pass

        return data


class FormUploadedFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files/%Y/%m/%d")
    field_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=254)


class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):

    form_builder = CustomFormBuilder
    submissions_list_view_class = CustomSubmissionsListView

    # ... other fields (image, body etc)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        # ...
    ]

    def get_submission_class(self):
        """
        Returns submission class.
        Important: will make your existing data no longer visible, only needed if you want to customise
        the get_data call on the form submission class, but might come in handy if you do it early

        You can override this method to provide custom submission class.
        Your class must be inherited from AbstractFormSubmission.
        """

        return CustomFormSubmission

    def process_form_submission(self, form):
        """
        Accepts form instance with submitted data, user and page.
        Creates submission instance.

        You can override this method if you want to have custom creation logic.
        For example, if you want to save reference to a user.
        """

        file_form_fields = [field.clean_name for field in self.get_form_fields() if field.field_type == 'fileupload']

        for (field_name, field_value) in form.cleaned_data.items():
            if field_name in file_form_fields:
                uploaded_file = FormUploadedFile.objects.create(
                    file=field_value,
                    field_name=field_name
                )

                # store a reference to the pk (as this can be converted to JSON)
                form.cleaned_data[field_name] = uploaded_file.pk

        return self.get_submission_class().objects.create(
            form_data=json.dumps(form.cleaned_data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),
            page=self,
        )
```

Comment: It works for me, but the submission list shows only the id of the uploaded file. How can I have it show an absolute link to the file? Thanks!

Comment: See the comment in the code example `get_data` `if field_name in file_form_fields` - you will need to do a DB query for the uploaded file and represent it how you want here. Or the docs contains an example of how to customise the submission listing view for listing only representation - https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/customisation.html#customise-form-submissions-listing-in-wagtail-admin and here is the code for the SubmissionListView https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/contrib/forms/views.py#L134

Comment: Thank you @lb-ben-johnston! I finished the if statement `if field_name in file_form_fields` with `file = FormUploadedFile.objects.get(id=field_vale)` but nothing happens. I must do something wrong.

Comment: When you log `field_value` (I have a typo above) - what do you get in the console.

Comment: I get an integer, representing the id of the uploaded file, I guess. (Sorry for the delay)

Comment: It sounds like your query is working, it looks like you are receiving the instance of the uploaded file. You might need to ask a new question about how to generate a link to a downloadable file from a file instance. Alternatively the docs should have info on this as a whole - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/

Comment: Hey, it might be helpful to note that I have posted a Blog post about a similar issue and it explains how to revise the submissions list view also, it relates to image uploads but is very similar. https://dev.to/lb/image-uploads-in-wagtail-forms-39pl